# Bounds on Conics Covering Point Sets in Two-Dimensional Space

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

For a given natural number $n$, let $S$ be the set defined as $\{0,1, \ldots, n\}^2 \backslash{(0,0)}$, which represents the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider a collection of conics $C_1, \ldots, C_m$ that do not pass through the origin.
(I) Demonstrate that if these conics collectively cover all the points in $S$, then $m \geq n$.
(II) Prove that if the conics $C_1, \ldots, C_m$ are lines, then $m \geq 2n$.

For starters:

A conic (including curves such as circles, ellipses, parabolas, and hyperbolas) is a curve described by a quadratic equation in two variables. The most general form of such an equation is
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
where $A, B, C, D, E, F$ are constants, and at least one of $A, B, C$ is non-zero. Consider the set $S:=\{0,1, \ldots, n\}^2 \backslash{(0,0)}$, which is the set of all pairs of non-negative integers less than or equal to $n$, excluding the pair $(0,0)$.

To complete a strict proof, is the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz a good idea?

At last, here's a more challenging and open-ended question: is is possible to improve the inequality $m \geq n$ for conics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's (I):

For conics not passing through the origin, WLOG we can set their equations $C_i: A_ix^2 + B_ixy + C_iy^2 + D_ix + E_iy  +1=0$ for $i=1,2,...,m$. By contradition, suppose $m < n$.

Firstly, define a polynomial $A(x,y)$ such that it is non-zero at each point in $S$ and zero everywhere else. In particular, we can choose
$$
A(x, y): = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (x - i) \prod_{j=1}^{n} (y - j).
$$

Next, define a polynomial $B(x,y)$ that is zero at each point on the conics and non-zero elsewhere. For each conic $C_i$, we multiply these equations to obtain $B(x, y)$. In particular, we have
$$
B(x, y): = \prod_{i=1}^{m} (A_ix^2 + B_ixy + C_iy^2 + D_ix + E_iy +1).
$$

We can see that $A(0,0) =  (n!)^2 \neq 0$ and $B(0,0) = 1 \neq 0$, but $A(x, y) = B(x, y) = 0$ for any $(x, y) \in S$. Also, the coefficient of $x^n y^n$ in $A$ is (1) , while the coefficient of $x^n y^n$ in $B$ is (0) by the assumption $m < n$ (so $2m<2n$).

Now, define
$$P(x, y) := A(x, y) - \lambda B(x, y),$$

where $\lambda = \frac{A(0,0)}{B(0,0)} = (n!)^2$ is chosen so that $P(x,y)$ vanishes on $S\cup \{(0,0)\}=\{0,1, \ldots, n\}^2$. We see the coefficient of $x^n y^n$ in $P$ is (1).

We then have that $P(x, y) = 0$ for any $x, y \in\{0,1, \ldots, n\}^2$, while the coefficient of $x^n y^n$ is $1\neq0$. This is a contradiction to the (two-dimensional version of) Alon's combinatorial nullstellensatz, which implies that we must have $m \geq n$.